# python parsing soup protocol response header and value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to write the question one more time because the first time the problem was not clear.

I'm trying to extract output from a SOAP protocol using Python.
The output is structured with a lot of subcategories and this is where I can't extract the information properly.

The output I have is very long, so I will bring here a short example from soapenv:Body

the original code (soap body)

```
<mc:ocb-rule id="boic"><mc:id>boic</mc:id><mc:ocb-conditions><mc:rule-deactivated>true</mc:rule-deactivated><mc:international>true</mc:international></mc:ocb-conditions><mc:cb-actions><mc:allow>false</mc:allow></mc:cb-actions></mc:ocb-rule>
```

As you can see I also used the command

```
xmltodict.parse(soap_response)
```

for turning the output into a dictionary

```
OrderedDict([('@id',
          'boic'),
         ('mc:id',
          'boic'),
         ('mc:ocb-conditions',
          OrderedDict([('mc:rule-deactivated',
                        'true'),
                       ('mc:international',
                        'true')])),
        ('mc:cb-actions',
         OrderedDict([('mc:allow',
                       'false')]))])
```

If there is an easier way, I would appreciate guidance

As I mentioned, my goal is ultimately to get each category its own value, when if there is a subcategory, a separate category will be added.
In the end I will have to put all the values into the Data frame and display all the categories and their values

for example :
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK20t.png)

I really hope that this time I was able to explain myself properly
Thanks in advance

i am trying to parsing soup response and insert all value and header to data frame

Comment: It doesn't seem like BeautifulSoup is relevant - it seems like you may be mixing up SOAP with SOUP?  If `mtasresponsegetvolte_response = '<mc:ocb-rule id="boic">...'`, then you should explicitly show that in the code block in your question.  The `for example:` section you have is not clear.  It would help us to answer if you formatted the desired output as, "this is the dict/list repr that I want, but I can't figure out how to transform X into Y".  I would recommend reviewing [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the reference and the answer, I made several corrections to my question